# apending Text in fluttre Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, append

I have number of Strings coming from an API.

What I want is to merge all Strings together...

What I've done so far is store all Strings in an Array and convert that to a String:

```
    var a = List<String>();

    a.add("\n \u2022 " + "test1");
    a.add("\n \u2022 " + "test2");
```

Result:

```
[•test1
         •test2
        ]
```

Expected:

```
bulleted lists without [] .
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You mean `concatenation` ?

Comment: Why don't you simply use `var output = '•Apple\n•Ball';`

Comment: @dm_tr Yeah , that's what i mean

Comment: @robo why are you using the `•` separator ?

Comment: The brackets are from a List.toString() method.  You can display that list in whatever way you want.

Comment: @robo please learn how to use SO formatting when posting questions by clicking on the `help` link next to the input box. Also, please take the time to fix your misspellings  and grammar before posting, otherwise you will not be so lucky to get a response every time and people here might downvote you, hiding your question (I edited the question for you already).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code sample should answer your questions:

```dart
void main() {
  const itemPrefix = " \u2022 ";
  
  // create a growable list of strings
  final strings = <String>[];
  
  // add some items to it
  strings.add("test1"); 
  strings.add("test2");
  
  // create a single string joining the items
  String result = strings
    // prepend the bullet point to each item
    .map((item) => "${itemPrefix}$item")
    // put a new-line between each item, joining the items to a String
    .join('\n');
  print(result);
}
```